# Exclude specific Rules in Spark SQL Optimizer

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark SQL (2.4.0) query involving a `UNION`. Now, I am trying to limit the optimizer to exclude a specific rule from its *physical plan* of the query so that Spark will make only 1 Exchange for both the queries. Here, I am trying to disable `PushDownPredicate`.

I have tried the below in vain.

```
SET "spark.sql.optimizer.excludeRules" = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate;
```

Query:

```
select a, count(*) as cnt
from tableA
group by a
having count(*) > 1000
and a = '12345'
union all
select a, count(*) as cnt
from tableA
group by a
having count(*) < 100;
```

I want the filter condition `AND a = '12345'` to stay after the `group by` but the optimizer keeps on pushing the filter down towards the source by a `WHERE` clause every time.

How can I prevent the pushdown and reuse the Exchange ? I am using Spark v2.4.0.

Note: *This is in reference to @David Vrba's talk on "Physical Plans in Spark SQL"*

Thanks

Comment: Not a fan of trying to trick optimizers. You have different having clauses here, I don't think there is any way to prevent hitting tableA twice. You could maybe try adding an interim table that is basically `select a,count(*) from tableA group by a`, and then have your unions pull from it.

Comment: Also, you can try doing it in one query using `having ((count(*) < 100) OR (a='12345' and count(*) > 1000))`.  Not sure if Spark will allow it, but worth a try.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your reply. Point taken. However, does the `SET` command given in my question above look correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the following and see if it works:

```
spark-sql> SET spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules=org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PushDownPredicate;
```